# How to draw a 2D boxplot in plotly?

Tags: javascript, plot, plotly

I'm trying to draw a 2d boxplot using js, plotly.js to draw a image ( to describe the distributions of two variables using box plots spanning both the x and y axes.)like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yxOQ.png

but in plotly I can only find boxplot like this:

```
var x = ['day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1',
     'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2']

var trace1 = {
  y: [0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3],
  x: x,
  name: 'kale',
  marker: {color: '#3D9970'},
  type: 'box'
};
```

https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/JKGMdQ?editors=0010

How can I combine horizontal and vertical boxplot and the do the same using plotly.js?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! One way of getting such a graph would be to combine a scatter plot with shapes, see: https://plot.ly/javascript/shapes/